# Pitting/spalling on a new cup in a hub

Tags: maintenance, bearings

It has been said that cones usually are the first to show signs of pitting, but in this case there is a single 0.1-0.3 mm wide dent on a new cup only after 80 miles of use. Therere was no play when checking the wheel lifted from the ground for play with one hand as recommended.

Comment: Did you use new bearing balls when assembling ?

Comment: Yes, had to use new set of bearing balls since one ball was missing from the start on a new Shimano FH-T610 hub.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds more like a manufacturing defect that has failed early.  A photo might help, but after 80 miles (130 km) it should be perfect still.

Suggest you contact the supplier immediately and let them know it has failed, then progress the conversation from there.

Comment: Had to contact the supplier already about ticking noise from the bearings (missing ball and lack of grease) on Shimano FH-T610. Since sending the wheel back seemed like a too much trouble had to overhaul it by myself. So it's impossible to tell anymore if it's a manufacturing deffect or some overlooked user error.